# LINQ to Entities query to verify all rows exist

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a need to verify that all the rows in a given set exist in the database and the current user has access to all the rows.  **I'd like to do this in a single query to the database**, something like a `.All()` query but I can't quite come up with the right syntax (maybe it's not possible).

The iterative version of the code would look like:

```
bool canAccess;
foreach(var taskId in taskIds)
{
    canAccess = await DataContext.WorkTasks.AnyAsync(wt => wt.DealerId == dealerId && wt.Id == taskId);
    if(!canAccess) break;
}
```

I was thinking about something like:

```
var canAccess = await DataContext.WorkTasks.AllAsync(wt => wt.DealerId == dealerId && taskIds.Contains(wt.Id));
```

But I don't think that's what I want.  Can this be done using LINQ?

Comment: That won't be the right test on `taskIds`. Any particular reason to use Async with an immediate `await`?

Comment: @NetMage - Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you using `AnyAsync` instead of just `Any`?

Comment: @NetMage for better thread usage in IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var dbCount = await DataContext.WorkTasks.Where(wt => wt.DealerId == dealerId && taskIds.Contains(wt.Id)).Count();
```

Will send all your IDs to the server and count the matching rows.

Comment: I sometimes see `.Contains` on a local list causing an error in LINQ to SQL but this seems to translate very well.

Comment: I actually went with a combination of @NetMage and @DavidBrowne answer, but David's is closest to the code I actually used.  David's answer is only missing the comparison of the database count to the `taskIds.Count`.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

To combine into a single query:

```
var q = DataContext.WorkTasks.Take(0);  // setup q to right type

foreach (var taskId in taskIds)
    q = q.Concat(DataContext.WorkTasks.Where(wt => wt.Id == taskId && wt.DealerId == dealerId));

var canAccess = (taskIds.Count() == q.Count());
```

Comment: That's basically the same thing as I have now, it ends in multiple round trips to the database.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the round trips issue. As long as taskIds is small, this should work.

Comment: Slight improvement in type setup makes for better SQL translation.

Comment: `taskIds` could be 20 - 30 items, theoretically a lot more but practically speaking it's not likely to be more than that.  The `q.Concat()` is interesting, what's the purpose behind that (as opposed to what David did in his answer)?

Comment: David's answer is better, but I am gun-shy of local sequences causing LINQ to SQL translation issues so I don't always think of using them. His use of `Contains` translate to good SQL I think.